# System font (SF Pro?), .rounded when using .custom — for iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

until now I have been using fixed font sizes, like this:

```swift
Text("Example")
    .font(.system(size: 24 weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
```

I am now trying to implement dynamic font sizes, so it scales with different accessibility modes. I found [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-dynamic-type-with-a-custom-font), which says "If you’re using iOS 14 or later you’ll find your custom fonts scale automatically with no further work from you". This does work for me, but now I can't find a way to make the font `.rounded` (as `.fontDesign` is iOS 16+, and I am targeting iOS 15).

Also, what should I use as the first parameter (font name) for the system font? I tried `UIFont.systemFont`, etc, which didn't work. I'm not even 100% sure `SF Pro` is the correct name here:

```swift
Text("Example")
    .font(.custom("SF Pro", size: 24))
```

Perhaps I'm doing this completely wrong in some other way that is not clear to me. Is this the correct approach to dynamic font sizing for accessibility — to use `.custom`, specify a default size (for the default type size), and let iOS scale this accordingly?

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond `.font(.title)`, for example?

Comment: Maybe, yes. I also saw `.title`, `.body`, etc (I guess there is a way to set the default sizes of those?) — but I can't find a way to use `.rounded` with that, either. I seemingly can't add any extra parameters and can't use `.fontDesign` for iOS 15.

Comment: The whole point of using `.title` and the other styles is that you do not specify any other properties. You get the appropriately sized and styled font based on the specified style and the user's accessibility settings. So it makes no sense to specify a style and a size. The style gives a relative size automatically. And if the user changes the settings while your app is running your app will automatically show the changes.

Comment: So, how do I specify the style? There's no way to set that in the user settings — there must be a way for me to set the weight, and `.rounded` in code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that if I remove the `.weight` parameter and use `.largeTitle`, etc, it works — and I can set the weight separately:

```swift
.font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
.fontWeight(.bold)
```

How do I set the default sizes of `.largeTitle`, `.body`, etc?

Comment: You don't set the size when using styles. That's the whole point. The user chooses the general font size in Settings.

Comment: Ah, ok. So just to clarify, does that mean, that there are a limited number of exact font sizes that you can use in any iOS app (that uses dynamic scaling)? I.e. no customisation can be made outside of `.title`, `.body`, `.callout`, etc — not even to change the font sizes slightly to better fit where they are (by a couple of pt sizes, etc)?