# Rounded font design with dynamic scaling in iOS 15+

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, fonts

I'm trying to use a rounded font design, with dynamic fonts. I am targeting iOS 15+.

I **cannot** use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/system(_:design:weight:)), as it's iOS 16+:

```swift
Text("Hello")
    .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
```

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/design) says `Font.Design` is available for iOS 13+, but I can't work out how to use it. I added `.fontDesign(.rounded)`, but it says this is iOS 16+ only. I can't find any example syntax using rounded with dynamic fonts (that works on iOS 15). I have scrolled through the list of suggested syntax, and tried inserting design parameter in various places... no luck.

This is what I was previously using for rounded font design, but this uses a fixed size font, which does not scale:

```swift
Text("Hello")
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
```

This works, but I want more control over the font size (e.g. not restricted to the preset `title`, `headline`, etc:

```swift
Text("Hello")
    .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
    .fontWeight(.bold)
```

Comment: It may help to point out that this is a follow on to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75053717/system-font-sf-pro-rounded-when-using-custom-for-ios-15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for something that isn't possible.  You can either specify a font size or you can use dynamic type.  Dynamic type requires that you use text styles:

[Scaling Fonts Automatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically)

> To add support for Dynamic Type in your app, you use *text styles*. A text style describes the use of the text, such as headline or body or title1, and lets the system know how best to adjust its size. You can configure text styles in either Interface Builder or your source code.

Your code in the "this works" block is exactly how you combine the rounded design with dynamic type.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for explaining, Paulw11. I must say, it seems a little restrictive to only allow a limited selection of font sizes? Especially if I want font scaling, but none of the text styles quite fit (i.e. I'd like to use a font size 1/2pt in between). I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311863/16370901) which suggested to use an extension and use a scaling factor on the text styles, but I couldn't get this to work, either.